# Create a wrapper for wine that runs under another user?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, wine

I have created a user called `wine` to run Wine under for two reasons:

1. any malicious activity can only damage `/home/wine`
2. Wine tends to pollute the home folder with heaps of configuration files in `~/.local`

However, I wish to create a wrapper for `wine` so that when run, sets the UID and runs Wine under that user.

So far, my current idea is:

1. create a `bash` script, `/usr/local/bin/wine` (remember that `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in `$PATH`)
2. this script will `gksu` into the `wine` user, running `/usr/bin/wine` (with full path, to avoid recursively running this script) with the arguments

This seems a little clunky though. Any other ideas?

What I have so far in `/usr/local/bin/wine`:

```
#!/bin/bash
gksu -D Wine -u wine /usr/bin/wine $@
```

*Edit: the script seems to be launching when opening applications, however Wine prints `Cannot find file` on stdout.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).